# how to avoid the overlapping of two object in the css?

Tags: css

I was following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6nmysZKHFU
can anyone help me with the css at the 8:10 he tell us the need to create the main tag so that the object that we create afterward don't overlap
I understand that i want to know is there any better way to do that .Can we do some tweak in the toolbar css to make it fixed so that other element will not overlap in the toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fixed position, you can use `position: sticky;` with `top: 0;`. Then you won't have to add any other element to avoid the overlap.

[Position Sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)

> This is basically a hybrid between relative and fixed position, which allows a positioned element to act like it is relatively positioned until it is scrolled to a certain threshold point (e.g. 10px from the top of the viewport), after which it becomes fixed.

Comment: Thank You so much for this ,will try this in the project :D